# ajax response to refresh url rather than append?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have a question regarding ajax, I'm quite new to it so not sure of the best procedure. Anyways I have incorporated ajax in to my CodeIgniter app but I have the possibility of 2 different responses and I'm not quite sure how to deal with this in my ajax.

Instead of appending my result to a div can I not just refresh the url?

In my controller I have form validation, when it is false I want to refresh to display my errors, but if it returns true I want to show the new page, if that makes sense?

view

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>part-one",
   $("form").serialize(),
   function(result){
      // if errors show this
      $("#error").html(result);

      // if there are no errors how do I check the response to refresh the page to a new url?
   }, "html"
);
```

controller

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
   $data['content'] = "part_one";
   $this->load->view('template', $data);
} else {
   $data['content'] = "part_two";
   $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you right then this code may help you ...

```
  $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>part-one",
   $("form").serialize(),
   function(result){
      // if errors show this
      $("#error").html(result);
if(result =='false condition response')
{ 
   window.location.reload()
}
if(result == 'True Conditon response')
{
window.location.href('URL of the page')
}


    // if there are no errors how do I check the response to refresh the page to a new url?
   }, "html"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload the page you can do;

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            location.reload();       
        }
    });
```